# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compiler-errors

I have the code below:

```
List<string> aa = (from char c in source
                   select new { Data = c.ToString() }).ToList();
```

But what about

```
List<string> aa = (from char c1 in source
                   from char c2 in source
                   select new { Data = string.Concat(c1, ".", c2)).ToList<string>();
```

While compile getting error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

Need help.

Comment: What is the final task and what is the source?

Comment: As far as your last edit mentiones the same source twice, see my answer #2 - it can help you.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> e = (from char c in source
                        select new { Data = c.ToString() }).Select(t = > t.Data);
// or
IEnumerable<string> e = from char c in source
                        select c.ToString();
// or
IEnumerable<string> e = source.Select(c = > c.ToString());
```

---

Then you can call `ToList()`:

```
List<string> l = (from char c in source
                  select new { Data = c.ToString() }).Select(t = > t.Data).ToList();
// or
List<string> l = (from char c in source
                  select c.ToString()).ToList();
// or
List<string> l = source.Select(c = > c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar_2: You should use `Select(x => x.Data).ToList()` to select the list of such datas.

Answer (score 12):

If you want it to be `List<string>`, get rid of the anonymous type and add a `.ToList()` call:

```
List<string> list = (from char c in source
                     select c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: What about List<string> aa =             (   from char c1 in source
                                    from char c2 in source
                                    select new { Data = string.Concat(c1, ".", c2)).ToList<string>();

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var lst= (from char c in source select c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: I cannot use var.. it has to be List<string> because of some reason

Comment: This way you will get `List<AnonymousType#1>`

Comment: @Rover: no it doesn't, .ToList() turns IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1> into List<AnonymousType#1>

Answer (score 2):

If you have source as a string like `"abcd"` and want to produce a list like this:

```
{ "a.a" },
{ "b.b" },
{ "c.c" },
{ "d.d" }
```

then call:

```
List<string> list = source.Select(c => String.Concat(c, ".", c)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers are below

```
List<string> aa = (from char c in source
                    select c.ToString() ).ToList();

List<string> aa2 = (from char c1 in source
                    from char c2 in source
                    select string.Concat(c1, ".", c2)).ToList();
```