# Cannot implicityly convert type System Generic List in XML Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net app with c# code behind. Trying to serialize to xml using a class. However getting the error:

```
 cannot implicitly convert Cannot convert type system.collection.generic.list
```

This line occurs at:

```
 CourtDocumentEvent = new List<DocumentEventCourtDocumentEvent>
```

.CS file code :

```
AddOdyDocToWorkflowRequest AddOdyDocToWorkflowRequest = new AddOdyDocToWorkflowRequest()
{
    CaseDocument = new List<CaseDocument>()
    {
        new CaseDocument() 
        {
            CaseAugmentation = new List<CaseAugmentation>(){
                new CaseAugmentation(){

                    DocumentEvent = new List<DocumentEvent>()
                    {
                        new DocumentEvent()
                        {
                            CourtDocumentEvent = new List<DocumentEventCourtDocumentEvent>()
                            {
                                new DocumentEventCourtDocumentEvent()
                                {
                                    DocumentData = CaseNumberTextBox.Text+ "," + DocumentCode
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256329/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerableanonymous)

Answer (score 0):

This code will will convert your object to XML

```
    public static string ConvertToXml(object obj)
    {
        StringWriter result = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(result, obj);
            return result.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return result.ToString();
        }

    }
```